# Query to search list of sObjects in the Organization

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I am trying to build a Visualforce Page where i want to display all the sObjects in the system with their related data counts in a tabular format.

ObjectName ObjectLabel RecordCount

Can i know how can i query the list of all sObjects and display in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example piece of code to fetch a list of all objects (and in this case add them to a picklist).

```
public class objectList{

 public String val {get;set;}

    public List<SelectOption> getName()
    {
      List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();     
      List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

      for(Schema.SObjectType f : gd)
      {
        options.add(new SelectOption(f.getDescribe().getLabel(),f.getDescribe().getLabel()));
      }
      return options;
    }
}
```

As you cannot predict the number of objects, you can't use standard tabPanel markup but you will have to use Dynamic Visualforce. Some documentation on using tabs in dynamic VF  [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_components_implementation.htm)

However, why would you go for tabs? Why not just display the complete result set on 1 page? That will save you some hassle with Dynamic Visualforce Components (which are not easy to use).